# How to get output parameter value from ExecuteNonQuery in enterprise library (c#)?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

my stored procedure is :

```
create Procedure spSetUser
(
    @Name NVarchar(50),
    @OrganicTitle NVarchar(30),
    @UserName NVarchar(20),
    @Password NVarchar(16),
    @Result Int Output
)
As
Begin
    Set @Result = -1    
    If Not Exists(Select UserId From dbo.Users Where UserName=@UserName)
    Begin
        Insert Into dbo.Users (Name,OrganicTitle,UserName,[Password]) 
        Values(@Name,@OrganicTitle,@UserName,@Password) 
        Set @Result = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    End
    Return
End
Go
```

and my class is (in microsft enterprise library):

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Insert)]
public Int32 SetUser(UserFieldSet Data)
{
    Int32 Result = 0;
    object[] values = new object[] { Data.Name, Data.OrganicTitle, Data.UserName, Data.Password, Data.UserId };
    Result = Db.ExecuteNonQuery("spSetUser", values);
    return Result;
}
```

Result is roweffected of execute stored procedure, but I want get value of @Result (output parameter of procedure), How can I get it ?

UserFieldClass is :

```
public class UserFieldSet
{
    public Int32 UserId;
    public String Name;
    public String OrganicTitle;
    public String UserName;
    public String Password;
}
```

Tip : I know must use this code for get @Result:

```
public Int32 SetUser(UserFieldSet Data)
{          
    Int32 Result = 0;
    DbCommand DbCmd = Db.GetStoredProcCommand("spSetUser");
    Db.AddInParameter(DbCmd, "@Name", DbType.String, Data.Name);
    Db.AddInParameter(DbCmd, "@OrganicTitle", DbType.String, Data.OrganicTitle);
    Db.AddInParameter(DbCmd, "@UserName", DbType.String, Data.UserName);
    Db.AddInParameter(DbCmd, "@Password", DbType.String, Data.Password);
    Db.AddOutParameter(DbCmd, "@Result", DbType.Int32, Int32.MaxValue);
    Db.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCmd);
    Result = (Int32)Db.GetParameterValue(DbCmd, "@Result");
    return Result;
}
```

But I can get it with this methd :

```
Result = Db.ExecuteNonQuery("spSetUser", values);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at `values[4]` after the call? does it get updated? although: it could well be that when using that signature, all the parameters are added as input only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using ExecuteScalar instead?

Comment: ExecuteScalar might be useful if you are after a single `select` value; I wouldn't expect it to change the `out` parameter handling any

Comment: Please update my code, I want insert data to my table and get valueof userid. How can i it ?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm doing the same thing you are and also changed it to use execute scalar, but still the out parameter is blank. If you got this to work, would you please share what you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I read the question, you have two implementations of `SetUser`; one that configures the parameters manually using `AddInParameter` and `AddOutParameter`, and one that just passes an array. If I understand the question correctly, the first approach works, and the second does not. And you want to know how to make it work with the less verbose second approach.

My advice: don't. The verbose code *works*, and more: it works for the right reasons - in particular, it is using pass-by-name, rather than pass-by-index, which should always be preferred.

My biggest question, though, would be: *why enterprise library?* - that adds very little compared to raw ADO.NET. If I wanted *convenience*, I'd probably be looking at "dapper", but even with this `out` parameters are a bit of a faff:

```
var args = new DynamicParameters(
    new { Data.Name, Data.OrganicTitle, Data.UserName, Data.Password});
// note: ^^ are actually specifying implicit names
args.Add("Result", direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

connection.Execute("spSetUser", args, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
return args.Get<int>("Result");
```

*Normally* it is a bit easier than that; for example:

```
connection.Execute("spFoo", new { id = -1, name },
      commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```